# What is the advantage of writing HQL in hbm file?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

i am writing HQL in hbm file like this

```
<query name="GetFabric">
        <![CDATA[Select F.FabricName,FS.FabricSeasonName from Fabric F,FabricSeason FS where F.FabricSeasonID=FS.ID]]>
    </query>
```

but we can write the query in code file so what is the better way to write HQL (HBM file or Code file)

Answer (score 6):

The main reason I would embed HQL into `HBM` files is simple:-

> The HQL meta data is parsed/checked/cached when the session factory is built

This means if you have errors you will know about them at the point your code starts up. Also the HQL is cached and ready to run. Using HQL in code means upon first run the HQL needs to be parsed and cached hence first time run will be slightly slower in code.

Answer (score 0):

If query needs to be exceuted in just single function i would embed it in code, However if I need to run this query in different project/class will put this in hbm.xml

Answer (score 0):

Named Query placed in the Hibernate mapping files are :

- more easier to maintain than queries scattered through the Java code
- global accessible, so you can define a query one time and use it several time in the code
- more secure, they prevents SQL injection attack

Comment: These three answers are also true for HQL in code. I am wondering why they are more secure?

Comment: They are more secure for SQL injection almost in the same way a stored procedure are ...

Comment: OK, understood you can't write `'from ClassA where id=' + id` in an embedded mapping file